# Does vim saving all edits in terminal history?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

[image]I have recently noticed a side bar at vim terminal that scrolls all they way to the first command I ran to get vim started. Every time I open an file using NERDTree or close a file I am still working on the same terminal, but the previous snapshots of vim are saved in terminal history. I can scroll all they way to the top and look at every vim command I ran and what file was open during that command.

I have never seen this happen before? Can I turn it off? If I press :q the file that was currently in the terminal shifts up and the new files shows up at the bottom.

Comment: A screenshot might help to illuminate your issue.

Comment: If you need more screen shots let me know. It seem kinds hard to explain exactly what is going on especially since it is not really a error.

Comment: Your TERM variable seems to be set wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to FDinoff I found the problem. The "term" variable was set incorrectly. I went to my vimrc file and commented out the exact line with "term" and vim now works perfectly fine.